# ggplot errors preventing plotting in R - factor has bad level

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the following couple rows of data from a much larger dataset, ggplot is breaking.

```
             Title - Year - Rated - Released - Budget-Gross #60 other columns
13  Alone in the Dark   1998    R   2005-01-28  2e7 8178569 
21  Are We There Yet?   1998    PG  2005-01-21  2e7 98114471
```

The only graph I can get to work is `geom_point`, but adding a `geom_smooth` causes an error: `ggplot(df, aes(x=Budget,y=Gross)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()`

The error is `Error in split.default(x, g) : factor has bad level`

And the full traceback:

```
29.
split.default(x, g)
28.
split(x, g)
27.
lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
26.
stats::ave(seq_len(nrow(munched)), munched$group, FUN = length)
25.
f(...)
24.
GeomLine$draw_panel(path, panel_scales, coord)
23.
gList(if (has_ribbon) GeomRibbon$draw_group(ribbon, panel_scales, coord), GeomLine$draw_panel(path, panel_scales, coord))
22.
f(...)
21.
self$draw_group(group, panel_scales, coord, ...)
20.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
19.
lapply(groups, function(group) { self$draw_group(group, panel_scales, coord, ...) })
18.
f(..., self = self)
17.
(structure(function (...) f(..., self = self), class = "ggproto_method"))(data, panel_scales, coord)
16.
do.call(self$draw_panel, args)
15.
.fun(piece, ...)
14.
(function (i) { piece <- pieces[[i]] if (.inform) { ...
13.
loop_apply(n, do.ply)
12.
llply(.data = pieces, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress, .inform = .inform, .parallel = .parallel, .paropts = .paropts)
11.
plyr::dlply(data, "PANEL", function(data) { if (empty(data)) return(zeroGrob()) panel_scales <- layout$panel_ranges[[data$PANEL[1]]] ...
10.
f(..., self = self)
9.
self$geom$draw_layer(data, self$geom_params, layout, coord)
8.
f(..., self = self)
7.
l$draw_geom(d, layout, plot$coordinates)
6.
(function (l, d) l$draw_geom(d, layout, plot$coordinates))(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]])
5.
mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
4.
Map(function(l, d) l$draw_geom(d, layout, plot$coordinates), plot$layers, data)
3.
ggplot_gtable(data)
2.
print.ggplot(x)
1.
function (x, ...) UseMethod("print")(x)
```

No idea what is going wrong here, any ideas? I am using the correct data frame in ggplot and the correct column names.

```
> dput(head(df7, 29)) #https://pastebin.com/ct9XSqG7
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `Budget` column is even numeric? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: When I print the data frame it has a `<dbl>` type. And if I `print(typeof(df$Budget))`, it shows `[1] "double"`

Comment: Don't use `typeof()` to divine that information. In fact, you probably shouldn't really use `typeof()` at all, there's no need. Can you edit into your question the results of `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: Your ggplot code runs fine (modulo small sample size on the loess) on the sample data frame you provided. You'll need to narrow this down to a data frame that you can share where the error is reproducible.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help!

Comment: When I try to graph on the head (`dput(head(df7))`) there is no error, but the graph is also empty. was it empty for you? I added the result of `dput` with 29 values from the head, which causes an error